# ontology application project

Tags: artificial-intelligence, project, semantics, semantic-web, ontology

I am looking for a project (application) that makes use of Ontology (for an academic course). Every body is talking about the health care application. I want to work on a different project. please any suggestion could help.

Answer (score 1):

I think that (almost) everything can be represented through an ontology. The idea behind it is to embed semantic meaning to the data you are putting into it.
Take for example [Swoogle](http://swoogle.umbc.edu/), it's a search engine that look into several ontologies to retrieve the information.
In the same way you can use it for any purpose:

- Tourism: travel information, retrieve meaningful suggestions to you clients
- Documents: search for topic that are related, not just by the keywords but by the meaning of those keywords
- Shopping store
- FAQs
- etc

The list goes all the way, if you can use it as a search engine, you can use it everywhere.